# Can a physical device have zero instance layers?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have a valid Physical Device: `m_physicalDevice[0]`.

I am trying to check the supported layers by my physical device:

```
    uint32_t physicalLayerCount;
    std::vector<VkLayerProperties> vkDeviceLP;
    result = vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(m_physicalDevice[0], &physicalLayerCount, nullptr);
    if (physicalLayerCount > 0)
    {
        vkDeviceLP.resize(physicalLayerCount);
        vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(m_physicalDevice[0], &physicalLayerCount, vkDeviceLP.data());
    }
```

I've verified that:

•The physical device is valid

•`result` is equal to `VK_SUCCESS`

The problem here is that `physicalLayerCount` is = 0, so the code doesn't run the `physicalLayerCount > 0` loop. Is it a hardware problem or is something wrong with my code?

(r9 270X is my GPU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Device layers are deprecated](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#extended-functionality-device-layer-deprecation), you shouldn't normally need to query them. For compatibility reasons, it's best to provide the same list of layers when you create a device that you did when creating the instance.

Apart from that, though, it's normal for there to be no layers of any kind: that's the common case on computers that don't have the Vulkan SDK or something like RenderDoc installed; normally only developers have those.

Comment: Darn, i just bought the Vulkan Progamming Guide, hopefully not too much of it is deprecated. Thanks

Comment: Nope, device layers are the only thing that has been deprecated so far.